# Why is the Locator snapping back to the original coordinates? How can I prevent this?

Tags: graphics, dynamic

Take the following code:

```
p = {3, 3};
Graphics[Circle[{5, 5}, 5], Epilog -> Dynamic@Locator[Dynamic[p]],
 Axes -> True, GridLines -> {{3}, {3}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Whenever I move the locator close to the original coordinates (marked by the grid on the plot), it quickly snaps back to them.  This means that I am unable to position the locator at around `{3.25, 6}`.  It will either snap to `{3.0, 6}` or to `{3.5, 6}`.  (Please see the image, it is at `{3.5, 6}` there.)

Is this a feature or a bug?  If it is a feature, how can I turn it off?  If it is a bug, how can I work around it?

Note that I am using `Epilog` because the graphics in my actual problem are slow to compute/render (large `ListDensityPlot`).

Comment: Hmm.... I cannot reproduce it on Win7 M.8.0.4 - all is smooth. What's your system and version?

Comment: I also cannot reproduce it

Comment: I'm on WinXP.  I got a confirmation in chat that someone else could reproduce it as well (I think on OS X)

Comment: @Vitaliy Does that mean that you can easily position the locator to any point between $x=3$ and $x=3.5$ for a given $y$?

Comment: I can reproduce it by even simpler code `Graphics[Locator[]]` (Win7 x64, M.8.0.4)

Comment: Both the OP's and Silvia's code work fine on my machine (Ubuntu 11.10, Mma 8.0.4).

Comment: On my computer, `Locator` works fine in `Manipulate` as `Manipulate[
 Column[{Graphics[Point[p], PlotRange -> 2], p}], {{p, {0, 0}}, 
  Locator}]`, but represents the "snap" problem when being directly used.

Comment: I have the same configuration as Sylvia, but am unable to reproduce this problem

Comment: Works fine with 8.0.4 on Mac 10.6.8

Comment: It must be Windows-specific: I have the snapping phenomenon on Win7 M 8.0.1, in both the OP's and Silvia's code; and no snapping annoyance under OSX M 8.0.1, in either of the examples.

Comment: I can reproduce the snapping on OS X in mma 8.01. The Locator only jumps near the initial point. I should add that no jumping occurs when I do something like `Graphics[{Circle[{5, 5}, 5], Dynamic@Locator[Dynamic[p]]}, Axes -> True, GridLines -> {{3}, {3}}]`

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes I pretty much couldl put it smoothly anywhere in that range.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it. A simpler code (reproducing Szabolc´s original question; Silvia doesn´t include the circle) would be `p = {3, 3}; Graphics[{Circle[{5, 5}, 5], Locator[Dynamic[p]]}, Axes -> True, GridLines -> {{3}, {3}}]` And, yes, I can easily position the locator to any point between $x=3$ and $x=3.5$ for a given $y$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems using an `EventHandler` to simulate a locator will be smooth on my computer ( press `Shift` instead of press mouse button to active the locator ):

```
p = {3, 3};
EventHandler[
 EventHandler[
  Graphics[Circle[{5, 5}, 5], Epilog -> Locator[Dynamic[p]], 
   Axes -> True, GridLines -> {{3}, {3}}],
  "MouseMoved" :> Null,
  PassEventsUp :> CurrentValue["ShiftKey"]],
 "MouseMoved" :> (p = MousePosition["Graphics"])
 ]
Dynamic[p]
```

**Update:**

I think it's the `AlignmentGuidesEnabled` feature which causes the snapping.

Here are another two examples which display the problem:

1. Putting the Locator in the "main part" of Graphics instead of in Epilog:

   ```
   p = {3, 3};
   Graphics[{Circle[{5, 5}, 5], Locator[Dynamic[p]]}, Axes -> True, 
    GridLines -> {{3}, {3}}]
   ```

   On my computer, the snapping occurs near the borders of the Graphics but not near `{3, 3}` anymore.
2. Different Locator actions in one Graphics:

   ```
   DynamicModule[{v1 = {2, 0}, v2 = {-1, 1}},
    Dynamic@Graphics[{
       Line[{{0, 0}, v1}],
       Locator[Dynamic[v1]],
       Locator[Dynamic[v2]]
       }, PlotRange -> 3, Frame -> True]]
   ```

   On my computer (Windows 7 x64, Mathematica 8.0.4), the Locator `v1` which linked to the Line moves smooth, but the Locator `v2` remains snapping.

**So it looks like the behavior of `AlignmentGuidesEnabled`. Use `Ctrl+D` open the "Drawing Tools" palette, there is a button at the bottom-left, toggle the `AlignmentGuidesEnabled` option off, the snapping will gone.**

Comment: Silvia's example 2 doesn't need DynamicModule: try `Module[{v1 = {2, 0}, v2 = {-1, 1}}, Graphics[{Line[{{0, 0}, Dynamic[v1]}], Locator[Dynamic[v1]], Locator[Dynamic[v2]]}, PlotRange -> 3, Frame -> True]]`. This runs smoothly.

Comment: Using `Module` instead of `DynamicModule` will bring a syntax color which indicates conflict. Anyway, I think the key is the `AlignmentGuidesEnabled` option. Did you observe any difference on Locator behavior between on/off status of that option?

Comment: It is indeed because of `AlignmentGuidesEnabled`!